# C++ reverse order of sentences

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to get a project done but I am having trouble with getting the order of the sentences reversed. The project asks to use a buffer of 500 characters where an array of characters that the user inputs will be stored from they user input array into this buffer of 500 characters. Each line after the user presses enter a null '\0' character needs to be added in place of '\n'. An array of pointers must also be created to store the first value of each sentence a user enters. Right now I am current trying to figure out how to read the characters till it his a null value in the buffer of 500 store it in a variable, then move on to the next set of characters till it hits null then swap them till they reach the end of the c-string.
Here is what I have coded so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;  

const int BUFFER = 500;  
const int POINTERS = 50;  
const int N = 30;  
const int HALF = 2;  

int main()  
{  
    char sentences[BUFFER];  
    char *pointers= new char[POINTERS];  
    int count = 0;  
    int index = 0;  
    char userInput[N];  

    do  
    {  
        int i = 0;  
        cout << "Enter in sentences: ";  
        cin.getline(userInput, N);  

        int length = strlen(userInput);  

        *(pointers + index) = userInput[0];  

        if (*(pointers + index) == '0')   
            *(pointers + index) = '\0';  

        index++;  

        *(pointers + index) = '\0';  

        do  
        {  
            sentences[count] = userInput[i];  
            count++;  
            i++;  
        } while (userInput[i] != NULL);  

        sentences[count] = '\0';  
        if (sentences[count] == '\0')  
            count++;  
        if (sentences[count - 1] == '0')  
            sentences[count - 1] = '\0';  
        i = 0;  
    } while (*userInput != '0' &&  *sentences < BUFFER);  

    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for `if (*(pointers + index) == '0')`? Why do you copy userInput to Sentences in a loop, not with strcpy or memcpy? `userInput[i] != NULL` is bad style because userInput contains char and NULL is a pointer. What is the sense of setting Sentence[count] to '\0' and then checking if it is that value? Also there is no need to set `i=0` at the end of the loop (just before i is destroyed). Comparing `*Sentences < BUFFER` is nonsense. And *please* don't call system, you can call getchar() instead.

Comment: FYI: It's customary not to name variables starting with an uppercase letter. It even messes up the syntax highlighting on this site... it shows `Sentences` with 'type' highlighting, not variable highlighting.

Comment: I was able to get the code working. I removed if(*(pointers + index) == '0') because it wasn't doing anything. userInput is supposed to take in 30 chars and then copy them into the buffer according to the instructions in the project. I changed userInput[i] !- NULL to '\0' As for the Sentence I check to see if the user enters zero then set that to '\0'. I removed the i=0 at the end of the loop. I removed the *sentencers < BUFFER since the teacher isn't requiring out of bounds checks anyways. as for the system call, I am required to use that in the project to get full points.